# How to get GPS Longitude and Latitude values up to 3 decimal points?

Tags: android, gps

I developed a GPS application , and i get the values like :

**78.38582246667-17.4532826666**

but i need like:

**78.385 - 17.453**

i am using DecimalFormating also. But i am not get the Logitude and Latitude upto 3 decimal points.

here is my sample code:

```
if (location != null) {         
    String credits = String.format("Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s", location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());       
    Double number = Double.valueOf(credits);
    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.000 EUR");
    String message = dec.format(number);
    Toast.makeText(Clockin.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //txt.setText(message); 
    System.out.println("GPS.."+message);
}
```

Comment: Why are you printing out EUR? and shouldn't it be 78.386

Answer (score 7):

Use Below Code line

```
DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
```

instead of

```
DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.000 EUR");
```